# Read null byte with pyserial

Tags: python, pywin32, pyserial

I've got a problem with reading null byte from serial port using `pyserial`. It is always replaced with `\xc0` and I can't understund why it happens.

Using debugger I found the source of the problem:
https://github.com/makerbot/pyserial/blob/master/serial/serialwin32.py#L233

`win32.ReadFile` stores data into buf where all bytes `\x00` replaced with `\xc0`

Comment: Code sample, please!

Comment: I solved the problem. It was in hardware.